# Extension Problem from Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right," 1.C, Problem 13. (p25)

Tags: linear-algebra

How can one prove/disprove this argument for an arbitrary number $n$ of subspaces?

> Prove or disprove that for subspaces $U_1, U_2, ... U_n$ of a vector space $V$ over $F$,
> $$U_1 \cup U_2 \cup... U_{n-1} \cup U_n$$ is a subspace of $V$ if and only if $U_1 \cup U_2 \cup... U_{n-1} \cup U_n$ is $U_j$ for some $j = 1,2,3, ..., n$.

A proof of this statement should involve induction over $n$, but this approach eludes my intuition.

Or is there a counterexample that disproves the claim?

---

Note: This is an extension of problems 12, 13 from Chapter 1.C of Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right* (4th ed).

Here is problem 13:

> 13. Prove that the union of three subspaces of V is a subspace of V if and only if one of the subspaces contains the other two.
>     (This exercise is surprisingly harder than Exercise 12, possibly because this exercise is not true, if we replace F with a field containing only two elements.)

Problem 13 is an *extension* of the previous problem, which involves the union of *two* subspaces, instead of three:

> 12. Prove that the union of two subspaces of V is a subspace of V if and only if one of the subspaces is contained in the other.

I know how to solve both of these problems, given that the number of subspaces (two, three) are rather small.

The approach (for the non-trivial direction) appears to be to assume that the union of subspaces (two or three) is a subspace, and then show that this leads to a number of possible scenarios - all of which involve one subspace containing all the other.

**But how can one generalize this argument for $n$ much bigger than 2 or 3?**

Comment: Hi, please change your images to words. You can use tools such as Mathpix to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement is false. Pick any odd prime $p$, and any $n \ge 2$. The finite field $\Bbb{F}_p$ admits an inverse for $2$, since $p$ is odd. The vector space $\Bbb{F}^n_p$ is finite, containing $p^n$ points, and we can express $\Bbb{F}^n_p$ as the (finite) union of all one-dimensional subspaces. That is,
$$\Bbb{F}^n_p = \bigcup_{x \in \Bbb{F}^n_p} \operatorname{span}\{x\},$$
but since $n \ge 2$, none of these subspaces are equal to $\Bbb{F}^n_p$.

Comment: Why is characteristic $\ne 2$ even relevant?

Comment: @TedShifrin As the question points out, it is possible for three subspaces to union to a new subspace in fields of characteristic $2$, but otherwise it's impossible. I think the question is just trying to get the reader to come up with a different, or more general counterexample? I don't know.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you for your answer, though I am still not sure about a certain aspect of your proof. For example, suppose $p=3$, $n=2$, $\mathbb{F}_{3} = [0,1,2]$, then $2$ has multiplicative inverse $2$ in modulo 3. Then $\mathbb{F}_{3}^{2} = [(0,0), (0,1), ... , (2,2)]$. Your proof says that $\mathbb{F}_{3}^{2} = sp(0,0) \cup sp(0,1), \cup ... , \cup sp(2,2)$, but how is each individual $span(x)$, say $sp(0,1)$ a subspace of $\mathbb{F}_{3}^{2}$?

Comment: @koala13 The span is always a subspace. One of the equivalent definitions of a span is the smallest subspace containing the set.